# Kafka consumer not consuming records and resetting offest for partition topic-0 to offset-5

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper

Running this application on multi-node kafka cluster and connecting to docker network using 0.0.0.0:19092,0.0.0.0:29092,0.0.0.0:39092. when i start docker-compose up, it prints log `Connection to node -3 (/0.0.0.0:39092) could not be established. Broker may not be available`

and after printing some logs producer starts listening `INFO Registered broker 3 at path /brokers/ids/3 with addresses: ArrayBuffer(EndPoint(localhost,39092,ListenerName(PLAINTEXT),PLAINTEXT)) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
kafka-producer_1_c40d8f3bc06f | 2019-04-28 16:42:43 WARN  NetworkClient:1023 - [Producer clientId=producer-1] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 1 : {topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

and consumer also prints something like this 
`kafka-consumer_1_c9be997eb7fa | 2019-04-28 16:42:44 WARN  NetworkClient:1023 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=foo] Error while fetching metadata with correlation id 7 : {topic=LEADER_NOT_AVAILABLE}`

````
kafka-consumer_1_c9be997eb7fa | 2019-04-28 16:33:23 INFO  ConsumerCoordinator:290 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=foo] Setting newly assigned partitions: topic-0
kafka-consumer_1_c9be997eb7fa | 2019-04-28 16:33:23 INFO  Fetcher:584 - [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=foo] Resetting offset for partition topic-0 to offset 5.```

but if i start running Proudcer application from IDE it consumes records.

why consumer not consuming in docker network?
````

Comment: 0.0.0.0 is not a valid connection string. You have a network misconfiguation

Comment: ohh sorry typo it's ```19092,29092,39092```

Comment: In your listeners settings, kafka-3 is loading with localhost, not its service name `EndPoint(localhost,39092`